# Birt report, dynamic label with action

Tags: eclipse, label, report, action, birt

I created a Birt handler class that creates labels in a report dynamically.

When I create a label I would like to create an action DrillThrough to link other report associated with the label in this way.

```java
LabelHandle label = elementFactory.newLabel("name label");
label.setText("text label");


//ACTION DRILLTHROUGHACTION
DrillThroughAction drillThroughAction = new DrillThroughAction();
drillThroughAction.setReportName("report linked name");
drillThroughAction.setTargetFileType("report-design");
drillThroughAction.setTargetWindow("_blank");
Action action = new Action((IHyperlinkAction) drillThroughAction)

label.setAction(action);
```

But in this way, the action is not applicable to the topic setAction in the label.

How can I build the DrillThroughAction for the label?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
LabelHandle label = elementFactory.newLabel("name label");
label.setText("text label");

// instantiate an action and link it to the element
Action action = StructureFactory.createAction();    
ActionHandle actionHandle = label.setAction( action  ); 

// Define drillthrough target    
actionHandle.setLinkType(DesignChoiceConstants.ACTION_LINK_TYPE_DRILL_THROUGH);
actionHandle.setReportName("report linked name");
actionHandle.setTargetFileType("report-design");
actionHandle.setTargetWindow("_blank");
```